# C++ How to choose file size as array size

Tags: c++, fstream, stdarray

I can't use file size as array size, because it should be a constant. But I made it constant.

```
ifstream getsize(dump, ios::ate);
const int fsize = getsize.tellg(); // gets file size in constant variable
getsize.close();

byte dumpArr[fsize] // not correct
array<byte, fsize> dumpArr // also not correct
byte *dumpArr = new byte[fsize]; // correct, but I can't use dynamic array
```

I need to create std::array with the file size.

Comment: Use `std::vector<byte>` and forget about `new`

Comment: `std::array` size must be declared with exact size at compilation time. it's IMPOSSIBLE to create it with some size at run-time, end of story. Your question is simply wrong

Comment: The array size doesn't only have to be a constant, but a *compile-time* constant. This means that the `fsize` initializer *also* has to be a constant, and `tellg()` is not.

Comment: Explain why you can't use a dynamic-sized buffer. If you are relying on VLA extensions (non-standard) to allocate an array on the stack, then you are at the mercy of the maximum stack size on whatever system you are targeting. So, if you know your stuff will always be less than some known size _and_ you don't want dynamic allocation then declare a static buffer at that maximum size and use it. If you don't know how large it should be you must use dynamic allocation. That's what it's for. If you don't need to read the entire file in one hit, then use a smaller buffer and process it in chunks.

Comment: *"But I made it constant."* There are different levels of constness in C++. An array's size needs to be a constant expression, that is a constant that is known at compile time. `const int fsize = getsize.tellg();` is not a constant expression, so it can't be used as an array's size. You can't make an `std::array` whose size is only known at runtime, it has to be known at compile time.

Comment: Why? You don't need to read entire files into memory. Process them a record at a time, a line at a time, or even a character at a time.

Comment: @user207421 because I need to iterate each 16 bytes of file. It's easy to get all file in one array and then std::copy from i to i+16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [**compile-time constant**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) to declare arrays so you have two options:

- Give up the idea to create an array and use a `std::vector` instead:

  ```
  std::ifstream file("the_file");
  std::vector<std::uint8_t> content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
                                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
  ```
- If the file you want to read isn't supposed to change after you've compiled the program, make the file a part of the build system. Example makefile:

  ```
  program: source.cpp filesize.h
      g++ -o program source.cpp

  filesize.h: the_file
      stat --printf '#pragma once\n#define FILESIZE %sULL\n' the_file > header.h
  ```

  ... and use `FILESIZE` inside `source.cpp` to declare your array.